# Animating Shader Noise Texture Node Randomly Every Nth Frame

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, mathematics

How may I move the Noise Texture every nth frame (e.g. 12 times per second)? I currently am using the `#frame` expression with Modulo, which does reduce the animation from every frame, but I'm not using it correctly. Can anyone please advise? Thank you!

[image: Animating a Noise Texture]

I'm seeking an effect like this:

[image: Noise]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Modulo`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math.html) operator outputs the remainder once the first value is divided by the second value. If you're on frame 21 and you do $21\mathbin{\%}2$ it returns $1$ and $22\mathbin{\%}2$ returns $0$ so your output only alternates between $0$ or $1$ since they are the only remainders for even numbers. I think what you want to do is $frame - (frame \mathbin{\%} 2)$ then you get even number outputs i.e. $0,2,4,6,8,10$.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was seeking, thank you, Harry!

Comment: no prob glad it worked out for u! :)